# Drop contents of schema without dropping the schema

Tags: db2, database-schema, db2-luw

In DB2, there is this `ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA` procedure which is used to drop a specific schema and all objects contained in it.

While it drops everything within the schema, it also unfortunately drops the schema.

Is there an alternative to `ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA` procedure which will only drop the contents of the schema but not the schema itself?

The reason I'm asking is we are testing a script on a particular schema which will create tables, views and triggers. I need to be able to drop the contents of the schema quickly but not the schema itself because I don't have privileges to drop and recreate the schema but I can do anything within the schema..

Comment: At present , the ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA does not fit your requirement. You will need to make your own solution. Easy if you are competent with scripting or SQL PL.

Comment: The typical solution is to drop/disable all constraints, then drop all tables and other objects from the schema.

Comment: ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA is not able to drop nicknames, try to create a nickname into your schema, run ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA it will fail but i should drop all other object